# do shell script results in command not found

Tags: terminal, applescript, sh

I've found sh-script for CPU Throttling and would like to schedule it on startup using AppleScript in the following way:

```
do shell script "sudo /Users/BohdanAir/Documents/Automation/cputhrottler.sh" "password mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

And get the following error:

```
error "sudo: /Users/BohdanAir/Documents/Automation/cputhrottler.sh: command not found" number 1
```

**P.S:** The pass provided to the `sh` file is being fully copied from the `Get Info` option (CDM + I)

Comment: **Do not use `sudo` together with `with administrator privileges`** See [TechNote 2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html). Remove `sudo`

Comment: While varian makes and excellent point, nonetheless the primary reason it errors out is you're attempting to execute a script that is not set as executable, or executed as a direct argument to the execution of a shell. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not even sure how you received that error message when the `do shell script` *command* shown in your question does not even compile.

The `"password mypassword"` portion actually has to be `password "mypassword"` for it to compile.

The reason you're getting:

```
error "sudo: /Users/BohdanAir/Documents/Automation/cputhrottler.sh: command not found" number 1
```

Is because `cputhrottler.sh` is not set as executable.

Make it executable using the following *command*:

```
chmod u+x /Users/BohdanAir/Documents/Automation/cputhrottler.sh
```

This will allow it to execute and not throw that particular error message.

Or use the following convention:

```
do shell script "sh /Users/BohdanAir/Documents/Automation/cputhrottler.sh" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges
```

Note that `sudo` was replaced with `sh`, or use other *shell*. In this manner the *shell script* does not need to be made executable.

Comment: You were right it's not the executable state and using the convention makes it execute perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Bohdan Afanasyev, Yes, to directly execute a shell script it has to be made executable, otherwise it has to be passed as an argument to the execution of a shell itself. Both methods will work, it's just a matter of preference. Personally I prefer to make my shell scripts directly executable vs passing as an argument to the execution of a shell.